# Ejercicio borrar espacio principio de líneas ficheros C

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio que se basa en quitar los espacios en blancos del principio de un fichero, lo he intentado con este codigo pero en el fichero 
auxiliar solo me salen `ÿ`, por todos lados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define filelenght
void borrarespacio(FILE *f);

int main() {
   char nombre[filelenght+1];
   FILE *f;

   printf("Introduce el nombre del fichero: \n");
   fflush(stdin);
   scanf("%s", nombre);

   f=fopen(nombre, "r");

   if(f==NULL){
      printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero. \n");
      return;
   }

   borrarespacio(f);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

void borrarespacio(FILE *f){
   FILE *fborrar;
   char leido;
   fborrar=fopen("borrar.txt", "w");
   leido=fgetc(f);


   while(!feof(f)){
      if(leido==' '){
         fputc('\0',fborrar);
      }
      else{
         fputc(leido,fborrar);
         while(leido!='\n'){
            leido=fgetc(f);
            fputc(leido,fborrar);
         }   
      }
      leido=fgetc(f);
   }
}
```

Alguien me podria ayudar con este codigo y a poder ser también con la busqueda de una palabra que aparece varias veces en mi código y necesito indicar la linea y la posicion en la que aparece. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: El `#define filelenght` no tiene tamaño, al usarlo en `char nombre[filelenght+1];` estás declarando una formación (arreglo) de un solo elemento.

Comment: Muchas gracioso perdón por el retraso, pero eso tiene que ver con que me salgan muchas y?

Comment: Si supiera cuál es tu problema: en lugar de un comentario te pondría una respuesta. Para que podamos ayudarte a resolver tu problema: debemos descartar todos los problemas no relacionados que pueda tener tu código. ¿Qué tiene que ver? Tal vez nada, o tal vez como sugiere [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138388/2742): todo. No lo sabremos a no ser que hagas las correcciones pertinentes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define filelenght
```

Estás declarando una constante sin valor, luego esto:

```
char nombre[filelenght+1];
```

Se convierte en esto:

```
char nombre[1];
```

Es decir, en nombre solo puedes guardar un caracter... ni tan siquiera una cadena completa porque eso requiere un mínimo de dos caracteres (las cadenas finalizan con el caracter nulo).

Lo que sucede si intentas almacenar una cadena en `nombre`es que acabarás usando memoria que no pertenece al array... es decir, pisarás memoria de otras variables que, a su vez, pueden sobreescribir lo que hayas almacenado en `nombre`.

En consecuencia, es bastante probable que no consigas abrir el fichero o vete tu a saber qué efectos secundarios pueden procudirse en la llamada a `fopen`

Tienes que darle un valor a `filelength`:

```
#define filelenght 100
```

Para tratar el tema de borrar los espacios en blanco, te sugiero, directamente, evitar copiar el espacio en blanco:

```
 int inicio = 1;
 while(!feof(f)){
   if( inicio == 1 && leido != ' ' )
     inicio = 0;

   if( inicio == 0 )
   {
     fputc(leido,fborrar);
     if( leido == '\n' )
       inicio = 1;
   }
   leido = fgetc(f);
 }
```

El problema que estás teniendo se debe a esta línea:

```
fputc('\0',fborrar);
```

... y a lo que te comenta [@JLDiaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138503/463)

Si introduces caracteres *especiales*, es decir, no imprimibles (se excluyen salto de línea y, si va junto al salto de línea, el retorno de carro), entonces el fichero pasará a ser binario y los lectores pueden interpretarlo de forma diferente.

Answer (score 1):

El carácter ÿ sospechosamente tiene por código 255, que es la representación del entero -1. Y digo sospechosamente porque ese es el valor que retorna `fgetc()` ante un error. Por tanto lo que está pasando es que la lectura del fichero te está dando un error, pero el código de error -1 lo tratas como un carácter y lo vuelcas al fichero de salida, donde se ve como ÿ.

De hecho, conjeturo que el programa en realidad no termina y acabas abortándolo con Ctrl-C, tras lo cual examinas el fichero resultante y descubres la retahila de ÿ, pero si estoy en lo correcto, al principio de ese fichero sí que debería estar lo que esperabas, eso sí, todas las líneas pegadas.

El problema proviene de que, una vez descubres un carácter distinto del espacio en blanco, entras en un bucle:

```
     while(leido!='\n'){
        leido=fgetc(f);
        fputc(leido,fborrar);
     }
```

pero en ese bucle ya no verificas si has llegado al final del fichero. Por ello, si el fichero de entrada no contiene `\n` (como es el caso a menudo en la última línea del fichero), llegará un momento en que alcances el fin de fichero, y `fgetc()` comience a retornarte -1 con el consabido efecto.

La solución por tanto sería cambiar ese bucle a algo de este estilo:

```
     while((leido!='\n)' && (!feof(f))){
        leido=fgetc(f);
        fputc(leido,fborrar);
     }
```

Aún así, este código no copiaría el carácter `\n`, por lo que en la salida tendrías todas las líneas juntas. Te dejo como ejercicio arreglar ese detalle :-)